# How to get RadioButton text in controller without using RadioButtonGroup?

Tags: view, controller, radio-button, sapui5

my view:

```
<FlexBox
    alignItems="Start"
    justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
      <m:HBox alignItems="Stretch">
        <l:VerticalLayout>
          <m:RadioButton id="rb-Yes" text="Quotation" select="changeKdsr" selected="true"/>
        </l:VerticalLayout>
      </m:HBox>
      <m:HBox alignItems="Stretch"> 
        <l:VerticalLayout>
          <m:RadioButton id="rb-No" text="material" select="changeKdsr"/>
        </l:VerticalLayout>
      </m:HBox>
    </FlexBox>
```

controller:

```
changeKdsr: function (e) {

        var rbText = e.getSource().mProperties.text; //this returns previously selected button text
    }
```

also this changeKdsr function is called twice, so I have to use weird logic to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two RadioButtons. If you select one, both are changed (one is selected, one is deselected). Two changes means two events. Thus `changeKdsr` is called twice.

So what you can do is check if the event is called for the selected button, then get the text.

```
changeKdsr: function (oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getParameter("selected")) {
        const oSource = oEvent.getSource();
        const sText = oSource.getText();

    }
}
```